# Optional Random ordered nested grouping in linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am really in a position where I can't think of answer regarding optional grouping in linq.

Basically,I want to generate report which comes from a screen having filters.
These filters(mostly grouped) are optional and can be rearranged.It's something like

```
Filters: 1.Clients Projects Tasks Duration
                or 
         2.Projects Clients  Tasks Duration
                or 
         3.Task Duration etc.
```

with all possible combinations.
Then data should look like

```
1.ClientA
     ProjectA
        TaskA
             26hrs 45mins
        TaskB
             43hrs 23mins
    ProjectB
      TaskX......
2.ProjectA
    ClientA
       TaskA
             26hrs 45mins...

3.TaskA
      26hrs 45mins
  TaskB
     6hrs 35mins
```

I have data.But unable to write logic which is generalized.

**I am thinking with some enum which will hold filters (viewmodel)selected like 
   enum.Client,enum.Project... and**

```
 if (clientGroupChecked) then 
     foreach(var clientGroup in list){
        //group list by client here
     if(projectGroupChecked) then
        foreach(var projectGroup in clientGroup){
        //group list by project here
}
}
```

I know,**it's wrong.This way I have to put logic for all the combinations possible**.
Couldn't think of anything else.**I want it really to be generalized** because it may have more filters added in future and I don't want to change entire logic just for extra filters(Of course,I want to add new filter group somewhere in the logic.But I want it to be more easy to maintain also.

**Edited:**
**@sschimmel** :My point is grouping can be shuffled(for this I have buttons[selected -->green and unselected-->gray and these buttons are movable for grouping].
So when writing linq logic,how can I know on what criteria I have to group in particular way? 
**For ex:** I have columns   A B C D E F.In this, I can just **choose to group by A or by A B or B A or ACB....etc**. with all possible combinations.How to achieve this?**I don't want if else check because we have many possibilities**.If one **more filter** is added,it would have many **more possibilities**. That's why I am thinking for **need of general approach** to do this.

**Edit 2**:

Please find attachment and how I am trying below.

```
    //for the following ,I need some way of writing properly passing right values
    var reportGroupingCP = (from t in TaskEntries
                          group t by new { clientId,projectId  } into g
                          select new 
                          {
                              ClientId = g.Key.clientId,
                              ProjectId = g.Key.projectId,
                             Result = (Type)g //What could be T
                          }).ToList();



   var reportGroupingCE = (from t in  TaskEntries
                          group t by new { clientId,employeeId } into g
                          select new 
                          {
                              ClientId = g.Key.clientId,
                              EmployeeId = g.Key.employeeId,
                              Result = (Type)g //What could be T
                          }).ToList();
    //Can't use above if there is filter only for client.similarly for other cases/I don't want to write for each one.I need way to do this dynamically.May be by passing enum or adding ids to some class or something else
```

[Filter 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnQPG.png)

[Filter 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2Q0z.png)

Comment: How does the input model look like? How should the output look like? How are you going to consume the output?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but it seems like you could just construct the query you need based on the chosen filters and then bind the resulting data to a control like a GridView for display.  Are you trying to do something more that I'm not seeing?

Comment: The query-side of things might benefit from using Dynamic Linq (https://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/), i.e. associate filters with string-based filter expressions, allowing you to add filters without touching the actual query-part of the code.

Comment: This question is very unclear. Can you please provide your sample source data in C# code? Can you please provide some examples of filtering that data?

Comment: @Enigmativity: I am trying my level best to put problem in simple scenario.I have no idea how to write linq for my situation.I am really stuck.I will try to explain again. For example,I have filters A,B,C(explained in Edited ques.).But these filters are optional and order is very important when grouping means I can group by A,B,C or B,A,C or C,A,B or just A or just B etc.Here I have 3 columns,so possible ways of grouping are 2^3=8.Grouping is dynamic based filters arranged in order.Please find structure in question. mentioned as 1 ... 2... which are scenarios of displaying my data.

Comment: @Avinashreddy - Please do not try to explain again. You are confusing me further. Can you please provide your sample source data in C# code? Can you please provide some examples of filtering that data? I want to see actual input and actual output that goes along with your question. Then hopefully the explanation that you've already given will make sense. You should read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you wan't to do group your data dynamically on multiple properties.

The easiest solution would be to use [Dynamic LINQ](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic) which lets you create queries from strings you can easily compose from user inputs.

```
// userSelections is created dynamically from what the user selected.
var userSelections = new[] { "clientId", "projectId" };
var propertiesToGroupBy = string.Join(", ", userSelections);
var groupedData  = data.GroupBy("new(" + propertiesToGroupBy + ")");
```

It's not type safe nor checked during compile time, but fairly easy to use and solves your problem. It's also [documented nicely](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic/wiki/Dynamic-Expressions).

I tried to come up with a solution that dynamically combines `Expression<Func<TaskEntry, object>>`s but got stuck on creating the `Expression` that ìnstantiates the anonymous type you would use inside the `GroupBy(new { ... })`. Because the number of selected properties to group by is not known during compile time, it's not possible to create the anonymous type.

Comment: So,I can't totally use this.But you are telling that way to do it is only through dynamic linq.Should I use expression and lambda to make this work along with dynamic linq to write with less magic strings(prefer none at all because I am passing only GUID type for group by)?. Even if I try to write some functions,I doubt that I can iterate and display dynamically with this approach(what do you say)[I mean what if there are four groups.In that case I need to use nested foreach more times.]

Comment: Please tell if following line helps you to proceed further with your way.I tried and didn't get anything.                                                                                                                 _data .GroupBy("new(" + propertiesToGroupBy + ")", "**it**")_; May be this will help you help me in moving bit further